# Proxy ivy repos with nexus

Tags: proxy, sbt, nexus, ivy

I'm using OSS NEXUS and trying to setup proxy repos for ivy.

There's article how to do this: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

I've successfully setup proxying of maven central, i see that nexus has cached artefacts while browsing these repos. But ivy proxying doesn't work.

I've created proxy repos (maven) for these urls:

```
https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/
http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/
```

And created group repo (proxy-ivy) for these four proxy repos.

I've deleted ~/.sbt and run sbt. There's outupt:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.13 ...
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/jars/sbt.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13!sbt.jar (604ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar (2932ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/jars/compiler-interface.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar (837ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/jars/actions.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar (1034ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/jars/main-settings.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar (984ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/interface/0.13.13/jars/interface.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.13!interface.jar (606ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/jars/io.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar (739ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/jars/ivy.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar (1642ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/logging/0.13.13/jars/logging.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.13!logging.jar (635ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/logic/0.13.13/jars/logic.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.13!logic.jar (573ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/process/0.13.13/jars/process.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.13!process.jar (720ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/run/0.13.13/jars/run.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.13!run.jar (628ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/jars/command.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar (749ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/classpath/0.13.13/jars/classpath.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.13!classpath.jar (596ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/jars/completion.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar (777ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/jars/api.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar (721ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/compiler-integration/0.13.13/jars/compiler-integration.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.13!compiler-integration.jar (635ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/compiler-ivy-integration/0.13.13/jars/compiler-ivy-integration.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.13!compiler-ivy-integration.jar (642ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/relation/0.13.13/jars/relation.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.13!relation.jar (588ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/task-system/0.13.13/jars/task-system.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.13!task-system.jar (649ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/tasks/0.13.13/jars/tasks.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.13!tasks.jar (610ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/tracking/0.13.13/jars/tracking.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.13!tracking.jar (555ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/testing/0.13.13/jars/testing.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.13!testing.jar (653ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/control/0.13.13/jars/control.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.13!control.jar (473ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/jars/collections.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar (795ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/classfile/0.13.13/jars/classfile.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.13!classfile.jar (642ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/jars/incremental-compiler.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar (811ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/jars/compile.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar (798ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/persist/0.13.13/jars/persist.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.13!persist.jar (672ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/cross/0.13.13/jars/cross.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.13!cross.jar (474ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/maven-public/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cf13e211b2cb31f0d3b317289dca70eca3362f6!ivy.jar (947ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/maven-public/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.50/jsch-0.1.50.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.50!jsch.jar (536ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/cache/0.13.13/jars/cache.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.13!cache.jar (669ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/test-agent/0.13.13/jars/test-agent.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.13!test-agent.jar (539ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/proxy-ivy/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.13/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.13!apply-macro.jar (621ms)
downloading http://nexus.hb.vmc.loc/repository/maven-public/org/scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/template-resolver-0.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar (290ms)
```

Seems like it works but i don't see cached artefacts in nexus

Comment: Why do you say ivy proxying doesn't work? I suspect you're mixing up caching with proxying but it's unclear (every line in your output is successful). Perhaps if you provide your code we might be able to reproduce your problem

Comment: May be i'm missing something but i mean that i can't find cached artefacts in nexus. I've setup proxying for maven central and it does proxy and cache, so i expect the same behaviour from proxying ivy repos